# Is it possible to create Avro schema for Dictionary object

Tags: c#, .net, avro, confluent-platform, avro-tools

Trying to implement avro serialization and deserialization in .net for kafka messages. Message model as follows.

```
public class SampleMessage
{
    public string Hash{ get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Content { get; set; }
    public string LineDetails { get; set; }
}
```

So, Is it possible to create Avro schema for **Dictionary** in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For that, you should use the complex type "map" (https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Maps

> Maps use the type name "map" and support one attribute:
>
> **values**: the schema of the map's values.
>
> Map **keys** are assumed to be strings.

Given the example, your .avsc would look something like this:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "SampleMessage",
    "namespace": "samplemessage",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "hash",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "fileName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "data",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "content",
            "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": "string"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "lineDetails",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```